# How do I access individual lines in a string?

Tags: c++

Say I have a string that goes:

```
"
199  
200  
208  
210    
200 
"
```

If I wanted to just access `"208"` for example, how would I do that after having read in the string input?

By the way, this is my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    int increase_altitude = 0;

    int previous = 10000;
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(s);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the position of "208" or should you find it and use it?

Comment: I don't know it

Comment: You have a good start with `stringstream`.  Now just use the stream operators like `>>` on it.

Comment: Do you want position of entered text or find or edit just at that point or what?

Comment: I just want to be able to access any of those numbers individually

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into multiple lines and then access it like an array. For this purpose I'm using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), but if you want to keep only unique lines you can use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

[TRY IT ONLINE](https://godbolt.org/z/9rGxPa7xc)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

static std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, const std::string &del = "\n")
{
    std::vector<std::string> val;
    std::size_t start = 0;
    std::size_t end = s.find(del);
    while (end != std::string::npos)
    {
        val.push_back(s.substr(start, end - start));
        start = end + del.size();
        end = s.find(del, start);
    }
    val.push_back(s.substr(start, end - start));
    return val;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string data = "199\n200\n208\n210\n200";
    auto lines = split(data);
    std::cout << lines[2] << std::endl; // 208 is at 2nd position, starting from 0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks good but I need something that works for when it's reading a really, really long input string rather than being like this: std::string data = "199\n200\n208\n210\n200";

Comment: @CSStudent This code will work for any amount of data

Comment: @CSStudent If this worked for you, you can upvote and accept this answer

Comment: @CSStudent This is a sample code that's why I have not written a *really, really long input string*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that you want a way to locate and isolate `"208"` as a `std::string`. As you have started, once you read you complete string into a `std::string` you can use that to initialize a `std::stringstream` which will allow you to read one string at a time from the stringstream. You can then simply add each string to a `std::vector<std::string>` (if you need to store all individually), or you can perform the comparison for `"208"` there and avoid storing in a vector -- that's up to you.

Collecting all strings in a vector and then locating the `"208"` string, you can so something similar to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main () {
  
  std::vector<std::string> vs {};             /* vector<string> for strings */
  std::string s {"199\n200\n208\n210\n200"};  /* input string */
  std::string tmp;                            /* tmp to read stringstream */
  std::stringstream ss (s);                   /* initialize stringstream */
  
  while (ss >> tmp) {               /* loop reading tmp from stringstream */
    vs.push_back(tmp);              /* add string to vector of string */
  }
  
  for (const auto& str : vs)        /* loop over all strings */
    if (str == "208")               /* locate string that is 208 */
      std::cout << str << '\n';     /* output (or use) that string */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_multiline
208
```

If I missed understanding your goal, just drop a comment below and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: I probably should've been more clear: Rather than find a string by locating a specific number, I want to be able to find 208 based on its position in the string, and be able to add/subtract/generally mess around with a whole host of numbers based on their position in the string

Comment: You can using the same approach. Once you have the strings separated in a vector of string, you can access by indexe with either `vs[2]` or `vs.at(2)`. You can iterate with a normal `for` loop above or use the same range-based `for` an taking the difference between pointer addresses when `"208"` is located. Either way is fine.